# @ConditionalOnProperty not works when the class bundled as lib and used in another application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I was creating a library which has a class to load some bean, I annotated the class with @ConditionalOnProperty to load only for those who need on their application.

Here when I keep this class in the same code then @ConditionalOnProperty annotation works fine as expected but when I create that class as JAR and add that as a dependency in the running application then @ConditionalOnProperty annotation not working.

Any suggestions on what I am missing here?

sample:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "bean", name = "enable", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@Configuration
public class MyConditionalClass {

    @Bean
    public Object createBean() {
        // code 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use @ComponentScan to include MyConditionalClass's package in Application class to try again as below

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.yourconditinal.class.package","com.main.package"})
public class Application {
}
```